# Change colour of Bokeh buttons?

Tags: python, button, bokeh

Bokeh supports button widgets:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#button

Can the colour of these buttons be changed to blue?

I have a set of [Checkbox Groups](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#checkbox-group) arranged in a column, and I need them to be separated by a header/button or something. But it can't be a green button. Hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way I am currently styling widgets etc...
There does not seem to be a way to directly change these in a python script only.

You will need a seperate .css file to style the widgets.
This also means you need to run `bokeh serve --show myappfolder` **and not** `bokeh serve --show myapp.py`.

Create a folder called myapp

structure should be:

```
myapp
|
+--main.py
+--Templates
   |
   +--index.html
   +--styles.css
```

index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      {{ bokeh_css }}
      {{ bokeh_js }}
        <style>
             {% include 'styles.css' %}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
      {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.bk-root .bk-bs-btn-success {
color: #FDFEFE;
background-color: #21618C;
border-color: #21618C;
}
.bk-root .bk-bs-btn-success:focus {
color: #FDFEFE;
background-color: #21618C;
border-color: #21618C;
}
.bk-root .bk-bs-btn-success:active {
color: #FDFEFE;
background-color: #21618C;
border-color: #21618C;
}
.bk-root .bk-bs-btn-success:hover {
color: #FDFEFE;
background-color: #5DADE2;
border-color: #5DADE2;
}
```

main.py:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button

button = Button(label="Test Button", button_type="success")
layout = layout([[button]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Now run `bokeh serve --show myapp` And you end up with:

[image: Resulting bokeh app]

Comment: Thanks! I think it's also possible defining the style in boxes.models.Div like the IMDB movie example, but I could be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Many changes were made to the layout of Bokeh 1.1.0, so I figured I would share how I was able to edit a bokeh button with css.

My file structure is: buttonBokeh/templates

Here is my buttonBokeh/main.py code:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button

button = Button(label = "Test Button", css_classes =['custom_button_bokeh'])
layout = layout([[button]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

And here is buttonBokeh/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      {{ bokeh_css }}
      {{ bokeh_js }}
      <style type="text/css">{% include 'styles.css' %}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
      {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the buttonBokeh/templates/styles.css

```
.custom_button_bokeh button.bk.bk-btn.bk-btn-default {
    color: black;
    font-size:12pt;
    background-color: #05b7ff;
    border-color: #05b7ff;
}
```

I run it on the buttonBokeh directory with:
bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=ip_address:xxxx buttonBokeh --port xxxx

Comment: Thanks! My initial thought is, that by no fault of yours it is a lot of code to change the colour of a button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `button_type` parameter. Options: ‘default’, ‘primary’, ‘success’, ‘warning’, ‘danger’

```
nextMonthButton = Button(label='next month', button_type="primary")
```

The '`primary`' is blue.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/enums.html#bokeh.core.enums.ButtonType

Comment: AFAIK, 'link' in not a valid button_type

Comment: indeed, the removed it probably. I remember it to worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a bokeh button (or any other widget), set the `css_classes` attribute, then add a style section to set the color of a button. For example,

`Button(label="PLAY",    width=100, css_classes=['b_play'])`

The add this to the style section of the page,

`<style>.b_play button { background-color: #98FB98 !important;  }</style>`

This method can be used to set other attributes, like font size.  Based on the state of your page, you can even disable a button...

`<style>.b_stop button { background-color: #A9A9A9 !important; pointer-events: None !important;  }</style>`