# Bokeh: Individual Colors for CheckboxButtonGroup

Tags: python, bokeh, dashboard

I'm trying to implement a interactive Dashboard in Bokeh as an application.
I managed to have pure python code to run the Dashboard so far, since I don't know much about JS.
I now like to change to color of the CheckboxButtonGroup. I have 3 buttons that each one should have an individual color.

```
label_list = ['This one should be green', 'This one should be blue', 'This one should be red', ]
colored_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=label_list)
```

Is there any way to style those buttons individually (preferably in python)?
In my mind I have something like this (which I know does not work since the CheckboxButtonGroup is not even subscribtable):

```
colored_button_group[0].color = 'green'
colored_button_group[1].color = 'blue'
```

I found a [related question for older Bokeh version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057328/change-colour-of-bokeh-buttons). However, I run Bokeh 2.3.0 and maybe there is now a simply solution for this.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The [API Documentation of the CheckboxButtonGroup](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.groups.html#bokeh.models.widgets.groups.CheckboxButtonGroup) is exhaustive and does not list a way to style the buttons individually for 2.3.0. Unfortunately that means you have to "hack" around and style them yourself, e.g. by injecting your custom css.